# parsing a line of text into multiple values

Tags: java, collections

This can be very basic question ... I am working with Java.
I am parsing a file in one of my classes. Each line in the file has 3 arguments (currently). I want to use one generic collection to store all the values at once

something like `List<String, String, String (and more args if needed)> list = new ....`. The number of arguments might increase later.

I am creating arrays right now to separate out individual args but that is not a proper solution. How can I declare a collection like that?

Comment: You haven't thought about a model class that represents a line of that file with its "arguments"? Would then be `List<LineModel>`.

Comment: What about a "list of lists of strings", `List<List<String>>`?

Comment: What's wrong with `List<String[]>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `List<List<String>>`

Using above collection you can have a `List<String>` on each index of the `List`.

To summarize it:

Each `List<String>` will correspond to a line in that file

and `List<List<String>>` will correspond to the entire file